# how to move the scrollbar scrolling automatically

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have added JTable to the Jscrollpane.But after moving down only all the contents are loaded.So i want to make scrollbar automatically goes down and again moving it to the top.Can i do that programmatically when loading jtable?

Comment: What are you using as a data model for the JTable?  It will be difficult to tell what the real problem is unless you provide code as a part of your question that is short, executable, and displays the JTable problem.

Comment: I think this is the wrong issue. You should try to display its content without needing to scroll down instead.

Comment: What do you mean all the contents are loaded? Consider posting your code to get better help.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: To go up and down look at Lifts model (You can find them at Airports , Shopping malls etc.).

Comment: Look at `scrollRectToVisible()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjtable%5d%20scrollrecttovisible).